# Log4j working fine on localhost, but in jenkins, all log statements printed on same line

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, log4j

After executing the test cases, all the log steps will be written into a file. Like as shown below.

- Log File created After executed in Local Machine:

> [INFO ][2014-04-16 16:49:02,945] - Reading data properties from dataSource file
>
> [INFO ][2014-04-16 16:49:02,945] - DataSource.properties file path

- Log file created After executing test case in JENKINS

> [INFO ][2014-04-21 08:08:27,134] - Reading data properties from dataSource file [INFO ][2014-04-21 08:08:27,135] - DataSource.properties file path

In Jenkins, after completing the first log statement, second statement will be added to it. But my requirement is first statement in first line, second statement in second line. So how can I specify the next line character in Log4j?

Answer (score 1):

In Log4j (v1 or v2), you can use `%n` in your `PatternLayout` to insert the new line character.
You can read more about Log4j patterns here:

- Log4j v1: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
- Log4j v2: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html

Here are Log4j configurations examples:

- Log4j v1: `log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%t] %m%n`
- Log4j v2: `<PatternLayout pattern="%-5p [%t] %m%n"/>`

Comment: Actually I gave pattern ="[%-5p][%9d] - %m%n" like this.It is working fine in local(windows os) machine but when i am running same pattern code in linux machine all the logs are creating in same line

Comment: Have you tried opening your log file in `vim`/`vi` on Linux? If you open your log file on Windows but the file was written by Linux, `\n` is used and Windows needs `\r\n` to insert a new line. To make it short, maybe the new line is here but you can't see it on Windows

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Actaully linux machine is in different location and through jenkins we are exectiong code. and creating log file as zip file and sending through email.please giive me the approch to resolve the issue.

Comment: Open your log file with Notepad++ or any other advanced text editor. Maybe your log files do not insert all events on the same line. Read my previous comment.

Comment: %n is the cammand given in pattern,is this works in linux machine for new lines..but it is not working?

Comment: Of course it does. Have you done what I suggested in my previous comments?